# XMLLINT not set and xmllint not found in path; skipping xml preprocessing

Tags: c++, xml

I'm trying to run the following command while writting in C++ with gtkmm-3.0 by following an [example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-buildapp-populating-window.html.es):

> glib-compile-resources --target=resources.c --generate-source exampleapp.gresource.xml

I couldn't find what's missing for this to work. I'm running on Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Do you have an environment variable `XMLLINT` set to find the executable for that tool?

Comment: The environment variable is mentioned here, are you trying something related? https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gio-2.0/Gio.Resource.html

Answer (score 7):

This is due to the lack of the XML processing utilities package on your operating system. You can install the `libxml2-utils` package by running the following command in your terminal :

```
sudo apt install libxml2-utils
```